# Mod_rewrite: easiest question? /admin should call admin.php

Tags: mod-rewrite

i know there are dozens of questions like this out there but somehow they never tell you how to do the easiest thing. i simply wanna pass for instance /admin in my url and admin.php gets called.

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^admin$ admin.php
```